Memory management problem in Tensorflow keras model
There appears to be a memory management problem with tf.keras.model.
When I call model.predict() / model.fit() {or just model(x)}, I observe that extra GPU memory is being used (although tensorflow has control of enough memory already!)
I have a tf.keras.model().
I am constantly tracking the memory being used by my GPU using 'nvidia-smi -l 1'.
When I run my python script, I observe that initially the memory used grows from 0MB/32510MB to 31460MB/32510MB. This is expected behavior because tensorflow takes control of around 90% of the total available GPU memory by default.
However, when model.predict() is called, I observe that the memory consumed grows from 31460MB/32510MB -> 31618MB/32510MB. This is surprising for me because I would expect tensor flow to allocate memory for model.predict() out of the memory that it already controls (around 90% of the total GPU memory). The memory already under the control of tensorflow is enough ( I am sure of this since I am using a very simple model and a very small dataset).
Why is extra memory being used for model.predict() in this case? Is there a bug in tensorflow's memory management?
Also, I observe that if I call model.predict() in a for loop with the same dimensions of input data, only the first model.predict() uses extra memory and the subsequent calls to model.predict() do not use extra memory.
This might be hinting at extra memory being allocated every time a new graph is traced.
I am concerned with this because if I call model.predict() enough times (with different sizes of input data), I eventually get an OOM (out of memory) issue.
Currently, I avoid this by setting memory limit to the gpu memory being used initially (I set memory limit to 22000MB/32510MB). So even though additional memory is being allocated during calls to model.predict(), the 10GB buffer is sufficient to handle this.
But surely, there must be a better way of handling this!
Is there anything I can do to to force model.predict() to use the memory that tensorflow already has control of?
Any help would be appreciated!
PS: I face the same issue when I call model(x), where x is some input data.
And I use tensorflow version 2.5
